# ACPI Error: [CP1] Namespace lookup failure AE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: boot, kernel, 18.04, acpi

I know there are already a lot of questions regarding this problem. Most of them say: use `acpi=off` option and you should be able to reboot. However, this is not the case for me.

I have been using my `Lenovo Thinkpad t460p` for over one year now. One month ago I updated it to `Ubuntu 18.04` and I have also `Windows 10` installed. I have had no problems so far and as far as I know I have not done anything to my `Ubuntu` system, but suddenly I get the error:

> ACPI Error: [CP1] Namespace lookup failure AE_NOT_FOUND
>
> /dev/sda6: recovering journal
>
> /dev/sda6: clean 12031023 files, 132130102/12939132 blocks
>
> You are in emergency mode ....
>
> Press Enter for maintenance...

When I do

`acpi=off`

I do not get the `ACPI` error but my ubuntu will still not boot as I can only press Enter for maintenance.

What are possible reasons for `Ubuntu 18.04` with a `Lenovo Thinkpad t460p`? I do not know how to fix this problem. Any help would be appreciated!